# QtCreator QMediaPlayer Meta Data returns blank QString

Tags: c++, qt, audio, metadata, media

I have a working media player using QMediaPlayer. It can open a song using a QFileDialog then play and pause it. I want to be able to read the metadata of the music files and use them as strings. I know this music has metadata as it shows up in Windows File Explorer. Here is the code that I have.

```
void MainWindow::playAudioFile(QString openItem){
     player = new QMediaPlayer(this);
     player->setMedia(QUrl(openItem));
     player->setVolume(50);
     player->play();
     QString albumTitle = player->metaData(QMediaMetaData::AlbumTitle).toString();
     ui->albumLabel->setText(albumTitle);
     qDebug()<<player->metaData(QMediaMetaData::Title);
```

The setting of ui text ends up blank and the qDebug print statement in the Application Output ends up blank. The Application Output in QtCreator also says `QVariant(Invalid)`.

Answer (score 3):

You do not need to start playing the media to get the metadata. However you do need to wait until the media is loaded.

When you call `player->setMedia(QUrl(openItem));` the actual loading happens in background (you can see in debugger Qt spawning a bunch of threads). setMedia() however does not wait for the media to be loaded, it simply returns. If you query for metadata right away, it may or may not be available depending on thread scheduling (i.e. depending on whether media has been loaded or not).

To retrieve it reliably, you need to connect to `mediaStatusChanged()` signal, and wait for the status `QMediaPlayer::LoadedMedia` - as soon as you receive it, you can query the metadata right there in its slot.

And, to get the best performance, please keep in mind that you can create more than one `QMediaPlayer` instance at a time.

Answer (score 2):

Try checking if metadata is indeed available through Qt

```
if (player->isMetaDataAvailable())
{
  /* YOUR CODE HERE */
}
else
{
  qDebug() << "No metadata.";
}
```

the [Qt Media Player example](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtmultimediawidgets-player-example.html) has all the code you need.

Comment: Using your code it still says 'No metadata.' Even though Windows Explorer has the Title, Track Number, Artist and Album for this song.

Comment: So Qt does not see the metadata. Which version of Qt are you using?

Comment: What file format are you using? Is the metadata you see in explorer actually part of the file (ID3 tags inside an mp3) or is it metadata attached to the file system? Qt might be able to see one but not the other.

Comment: I'm using Qt 5.2.1 and as far as I know the ID3 tags are inside the MP3. In windows, right-click-> properties will show me all the ID3 tags.

Comment: So after playing around I have realised that the metadata will only be 'available' once the mp3 is playing. That is only when I can access the metadata and it will actually display it.

Comment: Glad you found a solution.

Comment: The only problem is, I can't access the metadata without the file playing. Even if only the player is set to a certain file, it can't access the metadata.

Comment: I'm guessing Qt is trying to not touch the file until you actually use it and so does not open it until you play. Have you tried doing something like `setPosition` to see if it yields metadata without starting to play?

Comment: Hmm, I tried that, it doesn't seem to work. What I have found is that when I have `player->play()` (which is when I click the play button) I have the get meta data code afterwards. It will not retrieve the meta data until I click the same button again.